# What's the advantage of using "assume" for ignoring files in Git?

Tags: git, gitignore

There seems to exist two different ways to ignore files in Git:

1. Via the good old .gitignore file
2. Via `update-index --assume-unchanged`

It's not clear to me why 2 methods exist, and what's the advantage of one over the other (except that #1 seems to me more obvious to spot).

What are the real factors for choosing one over the other?